# Execution failed for task ':app:packageDebug' - Failed to read zip file

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

Without any changes in my code, suddenly i get this error when I try to run my app:

> - What went wrong:
>     Execution failed for task ':app:packageDebug'.
>     com.android.builder.packaging.PackagerException: java.io.IOException: Failed to read zip file 'C:\Users\Eliran\AndroidStudioProjects\Forum\app\build\outputs\apk\app-debug.apk'.

I have no idea why its trying to read the apk as zip file.

- **If I restart Android Studio, I can run the app once and then It happens again.**

Comment: This issue has been reported to the development team: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=210693&thanks=210693&ts=1463824240

Answer (score 9):

For me it helps (for now) when I `Exit Android Studio`, next I used `Windows Task Manager` (Ctrl + Shift + Esc) and kill process `Java(TM) Platform SE binary` and delete that file manually. After that I run Android Studio again, click on the `Clean Project` (there can be an error with app:clean, but you can run Android Studio again) and next click `Make Project` - after that of course `Run 'app'` button in Android Studio.

Comment: Its enough to kill Java(TM) Platform SE binary  and run the app again. It works for me.

Answer (score 4):

Its solve my problem perfectly. i Just delete my build file and file>> Invalidate and restart android studio. This problem occur for me change dependency version

Answer (score 3):

I try manual delete file, but the SO inform: the file "app-debug.apk" is in use by "OpenJDK Platform Binary". Then I kill "OpenJDK Platform Binary" and this worked.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using flutter, type

> flutter clean

and restart your ide. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

**After wasting my 4 hours i could fix this.**

I fixed it by deleting ~/.android/debug.keystore file.

Answer (score 0):

1.delete debug.keystore file

```
C:\Users\xxx\.android\debug.keystore
```

2. flutter clean
3. restart ide

Answer (score -7):

just delete debug.keystore file under .android

Comment: Can you explain how this answer solves the question being asked?

Comment: ...and your new debug build won't be installed to your phone due to incompatible signature.