# Execution failed for task ':app:packageDebug'. Cannot create directory

Tags: android

when I update my android studio to **3.0 beta7** ,Build failed with an exception.

> - What went wrong:
>     Execution failed for task ':app:packageDebug'.
>     Cannot create directory **F:\project\ my project path \app\build\outputs\apk\debug**

And I clear the cache,restart the computer and android studio,but it does not work at all,what should I do right now?

I kill process Java(TM) Platform SE binary ,and delete build cache ,it does not work either

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Execution failed for task ':app:packageDebug' - Failed to read zip file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37347291/execution-failed-for-task-apppackagedebug-failed-to-read-zip-file)

Comment: I have tried the answer there,but doesn't work

Comment: I have same problem.. Did you fix?

Comment: check following link for solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/55900617/3392323

Comment: check solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/55900617/3392323

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This worked for me!

***1.*** Open app.graddle file, and replace in applicationVariants.all... with

```js
android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.all {
            outputFileName = "${variant.name}-${variant.versionName}.apk"
        }
    }
```

***2.*** Build-> Make project
***3.*** Then Generate your signed APK

Answer (score 9):

I got solution from here [Migrate to Android Plugin for Gradle 3.0.0](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html#variant_api)

```
android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.outputs.all {
        outputFileName = "${variant.name}-${variant.versionName}.apk"
    }
}
```

Comment: i need to add date inside ?

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed the problem.

https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html

since the AS 3.0,Using the Variant API to manipulate variant outputs is broken with the new plugin,It can only be used to change the apk name,but not the path.

I have changed the output path in AS 2.3,so It build failed

Comment: What was the solution? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same issue but it is solved by following some easy steps:

1. Open **app.gradle** and replace **applicationVariants.all**  to this..

   ```
   android {
       compileSdkVersion 26
       buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'

       defaultConfig {
           applicationId "com.app.sample.news"
           minSdkVersion 14
           targetSdkVersion 26
           versionCode 7
           versionName "2.1"
       }
       buildTypes {
           release {
               minifyEnabled false
               proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
               signingConfig getSigningConfig()
               // change code from here to......
               applicationVariants.all { variant ->
                           variant.outputs.all {
                       outputFileName = "${variant.name}-${variant.versionName}.apk"
                   }
               }
              //here.... 
           }
       }
       compileOptions {
           sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
           targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
       }
   }

   /* IMPORTANT :
    * Be careful when update dependencies, different version library may caused error */
   dependencies {
       compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
       testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
       compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
       compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.+'
       compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.+'
       compile 'com.android.support:design:26.+'
       compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
       compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.+'
       compile 'com.balysv:material-ripple:1.0.2'
   }
   ```
2. Click on sync

Answer (score 0):

I looked for a solution for this in vain so I tried something drastic, I deleted the intermediates directory(app/build/intermediates), it worked.

Comment: While this is not an answer, Please use comment section to ask additional or supplementary question. Thanks.

Comment: Its, more of an answer than a question. But I'll put it in the comments section next time.