# Execution failed for task ':app:packageInstantRunResourcesDebug'. and My app can't run

Tags: android, android-studio

I wrote "Hello World" app in android studio so I can know that my ide is working (I'm running ide on linux and I'm a newbie so I don't really know what will happen.). Then, I run it and this error occur.

```
Execution failed for task ':app:packageInstantRunResourcesDebug'.
Internal error when trying to read zip file '/home/aukkawut/Downloads/hello/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/resource-debug.ap_'
```

So What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This link may be useful for you
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37574473)

Answer (score 0):

try with clean project and rebuild project.

goto Navigation at top of Ansroid Studio

`Build`-> `Clean Project` then `Rebuild Project`